# How to apply machine learning to 3D point cloud output which has different number of of points for each frame?

Tags: python-2.7, 3d, point-cloud-library, ply

Specifically, my question is every consequent frame has different number of points and KNN/SVM fails to implement unless I have the same number of points for each frame. So how to apply ml on 3D frames which have are different in size? My ply output file consists of x,y,z coordinates for each point and more than 10000 points per frame.

Comment: "Machine learning" is probably too vague. It sounds as though your problem is with a specific algorithm -- how about hyperlinking those acronyms?  That might encourage someone to try to figure out what you're up to. What do the points represent? Maybe you can insert an algorithm that interpolates over a given frame producing a fixed number of outputs. It looks as if there isn't enough information in the question to get a useful answer.

Comment: Whoever is downvoting, you should take the trouble to critique the question. An anonymous downvote isn't going to help a new user get up to speed.

Comment: KNN or SVM do not work by conducting point to point computation since each frame has different points. How can I compare two frames if each one has different number of points in generated cloud which have x,y,z coordinates information for each point?

Comment: Well for example, you could partition your space into cubes. For each cube, you place an interpolated point in the middle, that is formed by taking an average of all of the actual data points that lie within that cube.  But without more information it's hard to suggest an approach.

Comment: I am looking for a strategic advice. I have bunch of ply files (frames) gathered from a 3D camera. All the frames have different number of points. I cannot do point to point analysis since points are not matching in reality. If I take cube approach that u have suggested, I will be losing a lot of points in the cloud which may hinder my specific object detection attempts. What is the best way to overcome this problem of unbalanced point clouds? Any interpolation algorithm u suggest?

Comment: I assume that by 3-D camera you mean photogrammetry. I think you should ask a fresh question and make it very clear exactly what your task is. i.e. Give enough information so that someone could advise you on your best course of action. It may be that there already exists a technology to solve the problem.

Comment: Not an answer, but rather a question. As far as I understand the technology, a point cloud is derived from a depth picture. Why not going a step back and use this as the intut? I was just thinking on a similar problem, so it was interesting, what may be wron with such an approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [open3d](http://www.open3d.org/docs/tutorial/Basic/pointcloud.html) to downsample the points to a fixed number for all point clouds and then use deep learning libraries for classification or segmentation. [PointNet](https://github.com/charlesq34/pointnet) developed by the Stanford AI Lab is one of the best algorithms for this.

Answer (score 0):

If you have 10000points per pointCloud. It's a pretty decent data precision for a 3D object.  As a 3D artist, not a scientist I would try to find a hack. Like if your second pointCloud has 10065 points more or less. I will just ignore randomly the extra 65points on the second pointCloud so they match in length ( sum all your points number divide by frame number to get the reference value). But that can damage your data maybe (depends of how much they vary in length).

If I had to use scan raw data I would use a strongh geometry processing library like the C++ pointCloud library ? http://pointclouds.org/
and its python binding: http://ns50.pointclouds.org/news/2013/02/07/python-bindings-for-the-point-cloud-library/

Or a 3D software ? (Or tensor Flow ?)

Answer (score 0):

You can extract global descriptors from each pointcloud and train a machine learning algorithm like a SVM or an ANN with them.

There are a lot of different global descriptors, here you can take a look at a few of them: [PCL Descriptors](http://robotica.unileon.es/index.php/PCL/OpenNI_tutorial_4:_3D_object_recognition_(descriptors))

Once you have them train a machine learning algorithm like the ones shown in [Python Machine Learning Classification](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/supervised_learning.html#supervised-learning)